# notepad++ how to use regex in this case?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below notepad++ lines:

```
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,90902030
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,66000832
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,66553325
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,98781234
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,55596899
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,97370880
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,50224422
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,66208481
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,66164442
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,99226738
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,90036615
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,97141492
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,69040710
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,60401013
555,555,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Imported 3/19/17 ::: * My Contacts,Mobile,97818846
```

I want to add +965 right after "Mobile," so it going to be My Contacts, Mobile,+96590902030 etc..

how to do that? I've tried my best with failed attempts.

thank you,
regards.

Comment: Checked the ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need regular expressions to achieve your purpose.

In Notepad++ to replace, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace menu.

Then Simply Do a replace on `Mobile,` with `Mobile,+965`.

```
Find: Mobile,

Replace: Mobile,+965
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Using `Regex`**
>
> **Step 1:** Open `Notepad++` , Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
>
> **Step 2:** Now, Inside `Find`  Type: `\w*Mobile,`
>
> **Step 3:** And, Click On `Find All in Opened Documents` For Search Results.

**-: SEARCH RESULE FOR REGEX :-**

[image]

> **Step 4:** Now Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd> , Inside `Replace With`  Type: `Mobile,+965`
>
> **Step 5:** Now, Click `Replace All`

**Output:**

[image]

---

---

> **Using `Find and Replace`**
>
> **Step 1:** Open `Notepad++` , Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
>
> **Step 2:** Now, Inside `Find`  Type: `Mobile,`
>
> **Step 3:** And, Inside `Replace With`  Type: `Mobile,+965`
>
> **Step 4:** Now, Click `Replace All`

---

**Output:**

> **Before Replace**

[image]

> **After Click On `Replace All`**

[image]